# Customise database entries for every user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an e-commerce site where pricing for the prices are referenced in the prices table under the pricing model.

However, how can i be able to customise prices for individual clients for the same goods. How can i do that using the Price model.

I have tried adding user_id to the table but it seems have to price the same good for every individual client. How can i go about that?

The current table looks like this;

```
create_table "prices", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "country"
    t.string   "network"
    t.decimal  "price_euros", :precision => 10, :scale => 3
    t.datetime "created_at",                                 :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                 :null => false
    t.decimal  "price_ugx",   :precision => 10, :scale => 3
    t.decimal  "price_kes",   :precision => 10, :scale => 3
    t.decimal  "price_tzs",   :precision => 10, :scale => 3
    t.decimal  "price_usd",   :precision => 10, :scale => 3       
  end
```

Comment: It's impossible to help you if you do not provide your table structures and some example code of what you are trying to do

Comment: @user65439, check again

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways of achieving this. If each customer had the same discount across all goods, then you could add a discount attribute to the User model and apply this to the displayed prices.

If you want unique prices across the products which are unique for each user, then I would create a new model called UserPrice and have 3 attributes: `user_id`, `product_id`, `price`.

I would then have a method in my Product model called `price_for_user` along the following lines:

```
def price_for_user(user)
  UserPrice.find_by_user_id_and_product_id(user.id,self.id).price
end
```

When iterating over your products in the view, you could write:

```
<%= @product.price_for_user(current_user) %>
```

Obviously, you'll need to adjust variables as required for your situation. I would also index the `user_id` and `product_id` columns in the UserPrice table for speed.

*NB*: If it was me, in my controller, I would also consider looking up all UserPrices by user and creating a hash and then in the view displaying the price by doing a lookup in the hash. This might be quicker.

```
def index
  @products = Product.all
  @user_prices = UserPrice.where(user_id: current_user.id).index_by(&:product_id)
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= @user_prices[product.id].price %>
```

Comment: +1. As a note, a trickier (but more flexible) variation of the above is to assign users into price groups and to assign prices to those groups instead.

Comment: @Robin Thank you very much ... This is the real situation i have an sms gateway so i determine the destination and look up the price to charge.. currently,price is referenced as a constant across all currencies... i want to put these prices in adb, so destination is checked across the db for price. Hoever, i also want to be able to customize price for particular users based on negotiations

Comment: To clarify, do you want to display a price which is based on the location of the customer i.e. in your table, the field `country` is the destination country and `price_country` is the country of your user?